# How to use SEQUENCE to only insert unique numbers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working with pallets and they range from an ID of 10000000 to 15000000. This cycles a few times each year and the current solution is to have a table with the current `pallet_id` with a trigger which resets at 15000000 back to 10000000 and normally this was not a problem because by the time that happened all the numbers would be free again. This is now an issue and

I have been looking into using `SEQUENCE` instead of using this extra table with the trigger.

What I have come up with this far is:

**sp_Counter_NextValue**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [Database].sp_Counter_NextValue
AS int
START WITH 10000000
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 10000000
MAXVALUE 15000000
CYCLE
```

**Insert**

```
INSERT INTO X_PALLETS (sp_Counter_NextValue, information)
```

How would I go about it skipping a number for example when the number 10000000 exists in X_PALLETS when the counter reaches its maximum value?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a sequence.  You can define a `unique` constraint and cause the `insert` to fail and then retry until it succeeds.  Or, you could use a trigger that would increment the sequence until it succeeds, but I don't think you can do this automatically.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was afraid of this.

Comment: You'd run into the same problem if you used `IDENTITY` but tried to insert an existing ID, or ALTERED your IDENTITY's seed to start before existing values. Why not use a BIGINT for the SEQUENCE and start *after* any existing values ?

Comment: Does X_PALLETS only contain active records, ie pallet ids are deleted from table after they've been processed?

Comment: @destination-data Yes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because of customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final solution.

**Sequence**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SEQ_PALLET] 
    AS [bigint]
    START WITH 10010341
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 10000000
    MAXVALUE 15000000
    CYCLE 
    CACHE 
GO

CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SEQ_PICK_PALLET] 
    AS [bigint]
    START WITH 5541980
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1000000
    MAXVALUE 9999999
    CYCLE 
    CACHE 
GO
```

**Stored procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Counter_NextValue]
    @name nvarchar(24)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    declare @value bigint

    IF @name = 'PALLET'
    BEGIN       
        SELECT @value = NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_PALLET
    END
    ELSE IF @name = 'PICK_PALLET'
    BEGIN
        SELECT @value = NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_PICK_PALLET
    END

    SELECT @value as VALUE
    RETURN @value
END
```